# How to increment date range by a value from a date record in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have:

```
{"uid": 1111,
"from": "2015-11-07",
"to": "2015-12-31"}
```

And a date range as below:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2011-12-31', '2012-12-31', '2013-12-15', '2015-12-01',
               '2015-12-16'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='A-DEC', tz=None)
```

I turn `DatetimeIndex` into a dataframe. What I want to achieve is to increment a column called `count` by one when date exist in the range. For this example the below dates should have been incremented:

```
'2015-12-01', '2015-12-16'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
    In [1]: import pandas

    In [2]: index = pandas.DatetimeIndex(['2011-12-31', '2012-12-31', '2013-12-15', '2015-12-01', '2015-12-16'],
       ...: dtype='datetime64[ns]',  tz=None)

    In [3]: df = pandas.DataFrame(index=index)

    In [4]: df["count"] = 0

    In [5]: df.loc["2015-11-07":"2015-12-31"] += 1

    In [6]: df
    Out[6]: 
                count
    2011-12-31      0
    2012-12-31      0
    2013-12-15      0
    2015-12-01      1
    2015-12-16      1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I appreciate it.